# How to use Github API v4 (graphql) with javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, api, github, graphql

I'm trying to fech information using graphql and XMLHttpRequest with javascript at github, but when I try my code, nothing happens. I've tried the docs, but still don't get it.
PS: I just tilted and gave my personal token all access.

```
const githubURL = "https://api.github.com/graphql";
const token = "MY_PERSONAL_TOKEN";
const submitButton = document.querySelector(".botao");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", githubLoad);
let githubQuery = {
  query: `{
      viewer {
          login
      }
  }`,
};

function githubLoad() {
  let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", githubURL, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
  http.send(JSON.stringify(githubQuery));

  console.log(http.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much time, I've discovered that GitHub API V4 only works if I change this line:

```
http.open("POST", githubURL, true);

to

http.open("POST", githubURL, false);
```

No info about asynchronicity in the github docs. Just found at try and error.